# jQuery AJAX Cross-Origin Check for App Installed

Tags: jquery, ajax

I would like to check if a user has my app installed, which has been created with the protocol 'myapp://'.

On the click of a button, I would like to check if the user has the app installed, if they do, set the browsers location to the app URL scheme which will open or at least prompt to open the app, otherwise, direct the user to another page.

This is what I have so far:-

```
<div>
    <p>Do you have my app installed?</p>
    <button type="button" id="appinstalled">Yes</button>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery("#appinstalled").click(function() {
    var addr = "myapp://currentpage";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'HEAD',
        url: addr,
        success: function() {
            document.location.href = addr;
        },
        error: function() {
            document.location.href = "http://example.com/app-not-installed";
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately this fails due to CORS:-

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load myapp://example.com/index.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

So this obviously isn't going to work.

Is there an alternative method I can use? My website/app will be used in an environment primarily with no internet access, so I cannot direct the user to the relevant app stores.

Comment: How would this work if the error is specifically "Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP"?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (not exact) problem. This worked for me:

```
var url = "myapp://currentpage";
var method = "GET";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
} else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // XDomainRequest for IE.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
} else {
    // CORS not supported.
    xhr = null;
}

if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
}
// Response handlers.
xhr.onload = function () {
    //Whoo Hoo it worked
};
xhr.onerror = function (data) {
    //A million curses it did not
};
xhr.send();
```

Note: it did not work with ajax directly, whatever I did. I needed to to XMLHttpRequest directly.

**ALSO**: You need to set up your directory correctly where the currentpage is. You need to alter the `.htaccess` file in that directory for apache servers to allow access to all sources. That is massively documented on here, so I will not go through that again. However, if you are on a windows server you must change the `web.config` file **in the directory**.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```